# Is there a way in Google Analytics to check the javascript hashes typed in the URL?

Tags: ajax, google-analytics

I mean, for example an user types an address like this

http://www.mydomain.com/#hi_guys

Where may I handle this kind of hashes in Google Analytics?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the _setAllowHash allows GA to look at the hash data for parameters, but I don't think that it forces GA to report on the hash part of the URL. However, you can pass a parameter into the _trackPageview method which is recorded rather than the real path, so in this case you could do something like

```
pageTracker._trackPageview('/ajax/hi_guys');
```